# Simple telephone system to record kids' "calls"

Tags: linux, debian, modem

My four year old daughter loves playing with an old POTS phone.  She has these amazing conversations on it and I thought it would be nice to record them, and perhaps even let her pretend to make calls.

So, I have an old G4 Mac Mini with Debian on it.  It has a 56k modem built-in.  Can I use it to generate a dial tone and push enough voltage for the POTS phone to work?

Can I make it record her conversation after she "dials" a number?

This page gives the details on my Mini, although the modem is listed as "56.6k v.92 (internal)":
http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac_mini_g4_1.25.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought..
You could install asterisk (www.asterisk.org) on Debian, and configure it so that it picks up on any dialed number. After the pick up, it sends your daughter's conversation to a voice mail registration. I don't know if it can be done with a POTS phone and a modem, but you could buy her a cheap VoIP phone.. Unless the magic goes away, of course, because it's not her trusted POTS phone any longer..

Comment: You can make a SIP phone out of a POTS phone with things like http://www.internetvoipphone.co.uk/grandstream-handytone-701.html

Comment: Thanks @twan163.  I looked into Asterisk, but it appears that it only works with a very limited set of modems.  It seems that it's meant to work with purpose-built cards for big time VOIP users.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That's a nifty little box.  If it's a plain SIP phone, could I use something like asterisk for freepbx to manage it?

Comment: @bmauter. Yes, asterisk or freepbx will work with SIP phones. You could do tests with a software SIP phone first (jitsi/linphone...) before making any purchase. For asterisk/freebpx, you could try one of the many asterisk based distributions with a user-friendly web ui in a VM as setting up asterisk/freepbx can be a bit daunting otherwise for beginners.